# Is it possible to bypass the activation on an iPhone 5c that has "No SIM" issue?

Tags: iphone

I have an iPhone 5c with a No SIM issue.  I DFU restored it to no avail, still shows "No SIM".  I wonder if there's a way to bypass the activation so I can use it even if just on WI-FI.  Could jail-breaking it help anything?  Any other means?

Answer (score 1):

Try restoring it via an iTunes backup.